# Using mmap() to map for multiple processes to share memory region

Tags: c, pointers, memory, mmap

For a project I have to do I have to use:

`void *ptr = mmap(NULL, N, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, 0, 0);`

where `N` is the number of bytes of RAM to ask for from the OS.

When this statement executes, what is `ptr` pointing to? Is it pointing to the start of the shared memory between processes? Also, if in this memory space say I want to store 1,000 `int` pointers, do I need to have `N = 1000 * sizeof(int *);`?

And assuming that I am correct, where is the second place in memory that I can store something? Is it at `ptr + 1` or `ptr + 4` because an `int *` is 4 bytes on a 32-bit system?

Thank I appreciate it.

Comment: Yes, yes and at `((int*) ptr)[1]` (which is equivalent to `*(((int*) ptr) + 1)`)

Comment: Are you sure you want to `mmap()` a standard io stream? I'd recommend `mmap(NULL, N, flags, flags, -1, 0)`, personally.

Comment: This is what my instructor gave us to use to map a region of region between shared processes @EOF

Comment: Yeah, on Linux just using `MAP_ANONYMOUS` effectively implies `fd = -1`, but for portability you shouldn't write `fd = 0`. When in doubt, read the manpage.

Answer (score 1):

Since `mmap` is not defined in standard C, I'm assuming you're using this: http://linux.die.net/man/2/mmap

The return value is a pointer to the memory:

> On success, mmap() returns a pointer to the mapped area. On error, the
>   value MAP_FAILED (that is, (void *) -1) is returned, and errno is set
>   appropriately. On success, munmap() returns 0, on failure -1, and
>   errno is set (probably to EINVAL).

You are calculating N correctly.

However, you'll probably have problems using addition with a `void*` pointer, so cast your pointer to an `int*` to do addition.

```c
int* p = ptr;
int* nextP = p + 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> void *ptr = mmap(
>     NULL, N,
>     PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE,
>     MAP_SHARED|MAP_ANONYMOUS,
>     0, 0);
> ```
>
> where N is the number of bytes of RAM to ask for from the OS.

Here's one important constraint you *must* follow: `N` must be an integer multiple of the system's page size (or if mapping hugepages, an integer multiple of a hugepage's size). Usually it's 4096 bytes, but the actual value is reported by `sysconf(PAGESIZE)`.

> When this statement executes, what is ptr pointing to?

The beginning of the portion of the address space this particular mapping has been created at. With a non-anonymous mapping you can map the same memory several times at different addresses (this is a neat trick to implement transparent ringbuffers).

> Is it pointing to the start of the shared memory between processes?

At this particular point, it's just pointing to *some* memory. There's nothing shared about this *yet*. The mapping however will be shared after a `fork` (or a `clone` with the right flags); this already is process shared memory, but you probably will want to also `execve` into a different executable.

> Also, if in this memory space say I want to store 1,000 int pointers, do I need to have N = 1000 * sizeof(int *);?

Well, technically you need to have `n * sysconf(PAGESIZE) == N >= 1000 * sizeof(int*)`; however why do you want to share int *pointers*? Unless you have those *pointers* point into (another) shared memory region, that's at the same address in every process that uses those pointers, it's pretty useless to share *pointers*. Of course after a `fork` the address space of the processes is identical, but a `execve` will unmap all previous mappings, and you'd have to use non-anonymous `mmap` with `MAP_FIXED` and a filedescriptor obtained with, e.g., `memfd_create`, and use the first parameter of `mmap` where exactly to map it at (which might fail, or overmap a previously existing mapping).

What you can sensibly share is *offsets* and *bulk data*.

Oh, and just to eliminate any confusion: Placing a pointer in a shared memory region will not automagically share the memory it's pointing to.

> And assuming that I am correct, where is the second place in memory
>   that I can store something? Is it at ptr + 1 or ptr + 4 because an int
>   * is 4 bytes on a 32-bit system?

It's just plain memory, that you can use, as if it were allocated with `malloc`. Cast the pointer to whatever type you see fit and use it as usual.